# "Can't reach Google at the moment" when using Google Now

Tags: google-now

I have Nexus 4 running on Lollipop 5.0. Everytime I input a command via voice, or typing to set a reminder in Google Now, I get

> Can't reach Google at the moment

I've changed languages from English (US) to English (IN) with no results.

Does anybody know a fix for this? Alternatively, is there another way to set reminders via voice command just like Google Now?

Comment: Anyone searching for a fix either refer to the answer or you can check the discussion at https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/nexus/eoGV3ReWCrQ/wD3mcZL3zF8J

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had issue with reminders not working and that was "fixed" by going into app settings and then Accounts & Privacy, turn ON Search with Google.com

Now commands work properly? Must be a local server issue.

Comment: I didn't do anything. It just automatically started working after some days. Idk what was wrong.

Comment: Wow. I'd tried nearly everything short of throwing the phone at the wall but this worked. What's the best way to make GOOGL aware of this crazy bug, given it'll be outside the AOSP?

Comment: I don't have a "Search with Google.com" option. Is this in the "Google Settings" app > "Search & Now" > "Accounts & privacy"?

Comment: @harbichidian In google now, the app drawer icon (three stacked lines) next to google search box, Settings,Accounts & Privacy, Search with google.com = ON

Comment: @Darren unfortunately all I get are some Google Account options like SafeSearch and Nicknames (http://i.imgur.com/p43vltr.png)

Comment: @harbichidian You has less options than I do, not sure why.  FYI I have version 4.4.11.16

Comment: Make sure the 'Google' app is also updated in the Google Play store

Answer (score 0):

I only had this problem while connected to my home wifi.  It would only work once in a blue moon.  The other voice to text functions worked fine though.

I decided to log into my router and change the default DNS servers to some free opendns servers.  Fixed the problem right away.  Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I have the note 4 and I had to go into settings >> Accounts >> Google >> Search. There the option 'Voice & Audio Activity' was paused. I selected and turned the switch on 'On' and google voice search is back into action.

Answer (score -2):

In Google now cards...Settings>Now Cards>Delete card preferences

This will disable now cards.

Re-enabling will bring it back.

Comment: Does this fix the issue or is it just for disabling Now?